# Return an aggregated columnar result set in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How would I return an aggregated sum of customers' hourly data in a column representing each hour of the day? That question might be a bit vague, so I'll set the context...

I have a data set of Customers, each Customer has a meter, that meter is read every hour (think of an electrical meter for your house). Customers 1-X are assigned to Group 1, Customers Y-Z are assigned to Group 2, etc. I have setup a time tree in Neo4j (Year-->Month-->Day-->Hour) and the hourly meter reads are a separate node with an edge to the appropriate Hour (and an edge to the Customer). I need to return a report that sums up all of the hourly meter reads for all Customers in each Group (by Group), but each hour needs to be a separate column, like this:

GroupName  Date  H1Sum  H2Sum  H3Sum…H24Sum

The following query returns the correct format of the report but only for the first hour. How would I create an additional 23 columns of data representing hours 2-24?

```
MATCH (Group:LMRGroup)<-[:PART_OF_GROUP]-(SubGroup:SubLMRGroup)<-[:PART_OF_GROUP]-(c:Customer)-[:HAS_METER_READ]->(HrlyMR:HourlyMeterRead)-[:METER_READ]->(hr:Hour
{hour:1})<-[:HAS_HOUR]-(d:Day {day:5})<-[HAS_DAY]-(m:Month {month:3})<-[:HAS_MONTH]-(y:Year {year:2015})
RETURN 
Group.Name as GroupName,
m.month + '-' + d.day + '-' + y.year as Date,
sum(HrlyMR.Reading) as HE1
```

Thanks for the help and my apologies if this is still a confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a query.  I've broken it up to clarify.

```
MATCH (Group:LMRGroup)<-[:PART_OF_GROUP]-
      (SubGroup:SubLMRGroup)<-[:PART_OF_GROUP]-
      (c:Customer)-[:HAS_METER_READ]->
      (HrlyMR:HourlyMeterRead)-[:METER_READ]->
      (hr:Hour)<-[:HAS_HOUR]-
      (d:Day {day:5})<-[HAS_DAY]-
      (m:Month {month:3})<-[:HAS_MONTH]-
      (y:Year {year:2015})
RETURN 
   distinct(hr.hour) as Hour, 
   Group.Name as GroupName,
   m.month + '-' + d.day + '-' + y.year as Date,
   sum(HrlyMR.Reading) as HE1;
```

I removed your parameter on `(hr:Hour { hour: 1})` so that it matches all hours.  Then you just return `distinct(hr.hour)` to group records by hour 1, hour 2, hour 3, and so on.  The rest of the results should aggregate to the appropriate hour automatically, no need for a `GROUP BY` statement as you might otherwise use in SQL

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Returning the distinct(hr.hour) returns the correct sum of the readings for each hour, but the hours are still in rows. I need the 24 hours to be columns across the page. The Year, Month, Day will eventually be parameters passed to the query. I thought the Hour might be some sort of loop in the query, but I dont know how to make that loop return the summed hourly data as a separate column. The end report needs to be like:

Group    Date               H1   H2   H3...  H24
Group1  03-05-2015    23    45    67...   57
Group2  03-05-2015    45    56   90 ...   34